# Setting bool in ViewModel using RadioButtonFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a fairly complex form, but the problem I'm having is with a very basic part of it.  I have a radio button group with two radio buttons to represent a `true` or `false` value for a `bool` within my view model.  So I have a model like this:

```
public class MyViewModel {
    public bool IsPOBox { get; set; }
}
```

Then within my view I have the following code to produce the radio buttons:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsPOBox, true, new { id = "togglePOBoxOn" }) @Html.Label("togglePOBoxOn", "PO Box")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsPOBox, false, new { id = "togglePOBoxOff" }) @Html.Label("togglePOBoxOff", "Street Address")
```

The problem is, when I submit this with "PO Box" selected, the `IsPOBox` property is being set to `false` instead of `true`.  In fact, the property is set to false **regardless** of which radio button is selected.

Have I messed something up here?

Comment: What is @Label? Besides that, the code you are showing here is working fine. Can you show more code in the view and viewmodel?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I messed the labels up entirely.  I've fixed the code to show what I have now.  There is something important I forgot to mention, I'm using jQuery.click() to simulate a click on the radio button.  Is it possible that this isn't updating the radio button's checked status?

Comment: I tested it for regular postback. It worked fine. There could be something in your jQuery code. Can you show that code? Please share as much as possible.

Comment: @Yogiraj I figured it out: as part of the process of filling out the form, the user was making a selection that disables some fields, including the RadioButton.  For some reason ASP.NET MVC doesn't submit the values of disabled fields.  Annoying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out ASP.NET MVC doesn't include disabled fields' values when you submit a form.  The field was being disabled by a checkbox further up in the form.  Annoying!

Edit:
After seeing @JohnSaunders' comment below I did a quick search for how I'm supposed to have an uneditable field, but still have the information submitted.  It turns out you should use the `readonly` attribute.  I learned something today!

i.e.
`<input type="text" readonly />`

Comment: I believe it is the HTML standard that doesn't submit the values of disabled fields.